# R, Dplyr, Combine info by group and row/column specification

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column that has combined info from two columns, but one column is on a different row. Below is an example dataframe I want to start with:

```
df <- data_frame(person = c(rep("Joe",4),rep("Bob",3)),
               meal = c(seq(1:4),seq(1:3)),
               food = c("Chicken", "Beef", "Soup and meal 2", "Lamb",
                        "Lamb","Salad and meal 1","Beef"),
               dependencies = c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,1,NA),
               solo_meal = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1))
```

I want to create a new column that looks like:

```
data_frame(combined_meal = c("Chicken", "Beef", "Soup and Beef", "Lamb",
                              "Lamb","Salad and Lamb","Beef"))
```

If the dependency is used, I want to combine that "food" with the "meal".

I have a large dataset with several dependencies that I need to combine into one field. I feel like there should be a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to come up with one.

Thanks!

**edit:**
I want to thank those who have commented so far. The tidyverse option worked best for my needs. I have one edit that I meant to add - when searching through the meals - I may need to add more than one meal together.

```
df <- data_frame(person = c(rep("Joe",4),rep("Bob",3)),
               meal = c(seq(1:4),seq(1:3)),
               food = c("Chicken", "Beef", "Soup and meal 2", "Lamb and meal 3",
                        "Lamb","Salad and meal 1","Beef"),
               dependencies = c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,1,NA),
               solo_meal = c(1,1,0,1,1,0,1))
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5


  person  meal food             dependencies solo_meal
  <chr>  <int> <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Joe        1 Chicken                    NA         1
2 Joe        2 Beef                       NA         1
3 Joe        3 Soup and meal 2             2         0
4 Joe        4 Lamb and meal 3             3         1
5 Bob        1 Lamb                       NA         1
6 Bob        2 Salad and meal 1            1         0
7 Bob        3 Beef                       NA         1
```

I want to have a column of combined meals:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 1
  combined_meal         
  <chr>                 
1 Chicken               
2 Beef                  
3 Soup and Beef         
4 Lamb and Soup and Beef
5 Lamb                  
6 Salad and Lamb        
7 Beef
```

How do I recursively add the meals? Preferably using the tidyverse.

Thanks again!

Comment: Re your edit, why is there no dependency Joe's meal 4?

Comment: I forgot to update that column in the edit. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using the `tidyverse`. The idea is to self join the `df` table based on `person`, `dependencies` and `mean`, and then with some further operations.

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  left_join(df %>% select(-dependencies, -solo_meal), 
            by = c("person", "dependencies" = "meal")) %>%
  mutate(food.z = str_replace(food.x, "meal [0-9]", "")) %>%
  mutate(combined_meal = ifelse(is.na(food.y), food.z, str_c(food.z, food.y, sep = ""))) %>%
  rename(food = food.x) %>%
  select(names(df), combined_meal)
df2
# # A tibble: 7 x 6
#   person  meal food             dependencies solo_meal combined_meal 
#   <chr>  <int> <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         
# 1 Joe        1 Chicken                    NA         1 Chicken       
# 2 Joe        2 Beef                       NA         1 Beef          
# 3 Joe        3 Soup and meal 2             2         0 Soup and Beef 
# 4 Joe        4 Lamb                       NA         1 Lamb          
# 5 Bob        1 Lamb                       NA         1 Lamb          
# 6 Bob        2 Salad and meal 1            1         0 Salad and Lamb
# 7 Bob        3 Beef                       NA         1 Beef
```

Comment: This works the best of the answers so far, but I'm not sure how to implement it with the updated example I gave. I think I need a second round of joining, but that seems like it will cause more headaches than anything.

Comment: @JoeShmo I don't know how to solve your updated question. If my answer solved your original question, perhaps you can accept my answer and then post a new question with your updated question. By doing that, more people are likely to see your question and help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a base solution. (I find base solutions easier to understand.) You make an index vector of rows to modify and then build a new value from the items to be modified and the ones immediately preceding them ( which from your example appears to be the assigned task.

```
 idx <- which(grepl("meal", df$food))
 df[ idx, "combined_meal"] <- 
             paste( sub("meal.*$", "", df$food[idx] ), df$food [idx-1] )

 # The fill in NA's with the original `food` values
 df$combined_meal[ is.na(df$combined_meal)] <-
          df$food[ is.na(df$combined_meal)]



> df
# A tibble: 7 x 6
  person  meal food             dependencies solo_meal combined_meal  
  <chr>  <int> <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>          
1 Joe        1 Chicken                    NA         1 Chicken        
2 Joe        2 Beef                       NA         1 Beef           
3 Joe        3 Soup and meal 2             2         0 Soup and  Beef 
4 Joe        4 Lamb                       NA         1 Lamb           
5 Bob        1 Lamb                       NA         1 Lamb           
6 Bob        2 Salad and meal 1            1         0 Salad and  Lamb
7 Bob        3 Beef                       NA         1 Beef           
>
```

Comment: That seems like a big assumption to make, and not part of the OP's description of the problem.

Comment: Agreed it was an assumption but one would need to make some sort of assumption about what the intended replacement would be, since THEY WERE NOT DESCRIBED.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious that the replacement is the meal with the number that appears under "Dependencies" for the meal to be combined (e.g., for Joe, the dependency on row 3 is 2, which is beef).

Comment: It obviously was not obvious to me.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the base example, but I need to move between more than 1 line at a time. I'm also not sure if it fits the updated example I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Single line solution (using `dplyr`):

```
df %>% group_by(person) %>% 
mutate(combined_meal=ifelse(!is.na(dependencies), paste0(gsub("(.* and ).*","\\1",food), food[dependencies]),food))
```

For each `person`, we create a column `combined_meal` where if there are no `dependencies`, it repeats whatever's in `food`, and if there is one, it `paste`s together everything that comes before the word "and" with whatever's in the food column with the row number of the dependency.

(Note this assumes that the number in "dependency" is identical to the row number of the data frame if we only get the data frame for that person. That also implies the data frame is sorted by `meal`. If that assumption is incorrect, you can include the line `arrange(meal)` after the `group_by`.)

Result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   person [2]
  person  meal food             dependencies solo_meal combined_meal 
  <chr>  <int> <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         
1 Joe        1 Chicken                   NA         1. Chicken       
2 Joe        2 Beef                      NA         1. Beef          
3 Joe        3 Soup and meal 2            2.        0. Soup and Beef 
4 Joe        4 Lamb                      NA         1. Lamb          
5 Bob        1 Lamb                      NA         1. Lamb          
6 Bob        2 Salad and meal 1           1.        0. Salad and Lamb
7 Bob        3 Beef                      NA         1. Beef
```